# Laravel: get() returning array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple eloquent query:

```
$comments = Comment::where('approved',1)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

return view('comments.approved', compact('comments'));
```

I am trying to access the data in view using the following syntax

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)

{{ $comment->content }}

@endforeach
```

I am getting the following error

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: ...
```

I was able to resolve the problem by either of these

```
{{ @$comment->content }}
or
{{ $comment['content'] }}
```

However, I fail to understand why get() is returning an array instead of collection. Isn't get() suppose to return collection of objects?

Answer (score 2):

PHP compact() does this, according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

```
Creates an array containing variables and their values.
```

So you're changing it to an array as you pass it to your view. Try it without using compact() and see if you get the response you're expecting.

```
return view('comments.approved', ['comments' => $comments]);
```